# htaccess - IP canonicalization to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

Bitnami wordpress on Google Cloud.

Ok, the below code, diverts all to https non-www which works great, but the issue is we can't get the dedicated IP to redirect to https url. Please see below;

```
RewriteEngine on


<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /

# IP REDIRECT CONANIZATION
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^00\.00\.93\.114$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]


### WORKING HTTP to HTTPS / NON-WWW - WORKS

#if not example.co.uk then redirect to example.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#if not https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#redirect to https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

From the configuration file you are sharing here, it seems to me that you are trying to redirect all the incoming requests to https://example.co.uk, is this true?

In order to do so, you can edit the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` file and set the following lines

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk$1 [R=permanent,L]
...

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk$1 [R=permanent,L]
...
```

More information here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/components/apache/#how-to-access-my-application-from-only-one-domain